# How to removeConstraint defaultValue in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, database-migration, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to write a migration in Sequelize and want to remove the defaultValue constraint.  What is the proper syntax?  I've tried both of the following:

```
return queryInterface.removeConstraint('Table', 'table_columnName_default')
return queryInterface.removeConstraint('Table', 'columnName_default')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you please try to use

```
return queryInterface.changeColumn('Table', 'attributeName', {
    defaultValue: null,
    allowNull: true,
});
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-changeColumn

Comment: I edited the answer above to add type -- this is necessary else the migration fails.

Comment: Not working for me, generated SQL looks like this: `ALTER TABLE 'Table' CHANGE 'attributeName' 'attributeName' VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a raw query:

```
return queryInterface.sequelize.query(`ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column DROP DEFAULT;`)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should know the data type. for e.g. `STRING`:

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

return queryInterface.changeColumn('Table', 'attributeName', {
    defaultValue: null,
    type: DataTypes.STRING
});
```

you can also use `queryInterface` from the `model` definition (or pass the model/query interface) to make it generic for any column with default value:

```
function dropDefaults(queryInterface, model) {
  const defaultValues = Object.keys(model._defaultValues);
  for (const column of defaultValues) {
    model.queryInterface.changeColumn(model.tableName, column, {
      defaultValue: null,
      type: model.fieldRawAttributesMap[column].type,
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me `defaultValue: null` was not working, as it was trying to set the default value to `NULL` rather than removing it.

What worked for me was supplying the whole column definition, but without a `defaultValue`:

```js
await queryInterface.changeColumn('Table', 'columnName', {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT // or whatever is your data type
});
```